# Google Maps API within Signin

Tags: google-maps

I have the following code. One thing I don't like it how it has the Sign-In option. Is there a way to remove this by tweaking the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Info windows</title>
        <style>
          html, body, #map-canvas {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
         }

        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
        <script>

    function initialize() {
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.8833,-77.0167);
     var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng
      };



      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

      var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
          '<div id="siteNotice">'+
          '</div>'+
          '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
          '<div id="bodyContent">'+
          '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
           'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
          'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
          'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
          '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
          'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
           'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
          'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
          'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
         'Heritage Site.</p>'+
         '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
          'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
         '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
         '</div>'+
         '</div>';

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         content: contentString
      });


      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
      });


      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infowindow.open(map,marker);
     });
    }

     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
      </head>
     <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `signed_in`-parameter from the API-URL

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
```